# tkinter: Modifying attributes of hidden widget - Widget doesn't stay hidden (python 3.6)

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using  `.grid_remove()` on *Frame* widgets (to hide all widgets inside the frame) and must update attributes of the hidden widgets *without* those widgets being automagically 
displayed.  (BTW using `.grid_forget()` didn't seem to change things.)  I seem to remember reading that this "display upon update" behaviour is intentional (which make some sense) but how do I stop it from happening?

Have I overlooked something obvious?  Is there an alternative to using `.grid_remove()` on all widgets that are inside the hideable frames?

Background:

This is for a multilingual application that has multiple modes of operation.  Depending on the user mode some widgets must be hidden.  When a user selects a language (using the GUI) the `text` attribute of  *every* widget (including the hidden ones) must change accordingly, resulting in the hidden widgets (which are inappropriate in some operating modes) to appear on the display.

The following pseudocode shows the sequence of events.  At startup (which determines the operational mode):

```
UserMode = RestrictedMode
WidgetTitle = 'This restricted mode widget is invisible'
Ghost_Frame = LabelFrame( ParentFrame )
Ghost_Frame.grid()    
GhostWidget = LabelFrame( Ghost_Frame ) # widget type doesn't matter
GhostWidget.grid()
GhostWidget[ 'text' ] = WidgetTitle     # or GhostWidget.configure( text = WidgetTitle )
if ( UserMode == RestrictedMode ) :
     Ghost_Frame.grid_remove( )         # hide frame and GhostWidget
```

Everything works as expected (`GhostWidget` does not appear) - until the user uses the GUI to select a language, causing this to be executed:

```
WidgetTitle = 'The restricted mode widget is now visible' 
GhostWidget[ 'text' ] = WidgetTitle
```

Which causes `GhostWidget` to become visible *to the restricted user* instead of staying hidden.  Note that temporarily commenting out the above line eliminates (hides?) the problem.

Finally, in my case conditionally executing `.grid_remove()` lines according to user mode is not really a practical option due to the number of prompts, modes and modules involved.

Comment: I've used `grid_forget` to hide and `grid` again to show elements without issue in the past. Perhaps you can post a minimal example to test?

Comment: Simply changing a widget won't force it to be displayed. You must be doing something to cause it to be displayed. Please post a [mcve]. Pseudocode is useless.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that modifying hidden widgets shouldn't be the cause of my problem - and for setting me on the right track.  (I suspected that was the case but couldn't find anything on-line that documents the situation.)  So far the example code I'm building doesn't have my problem.  I'm going to go through the real code with a fine toothed comb to find the cause.  Regardless , I'll update the question.

Comment: As expected, and as per explanation below, it wasn't a grid_remove() issue - it just looked like the cause. Hopefully my experience will help others avoid the pitfall I fell into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I led myself down the garden path and fell into a pitfall.  I'm posting the cause here so others may profit from my misadventure.

Unlike all other widgets,  the problem widgets were not being hidden by the use of  .grid_remove().  Instead they were being made "invisible" by setting the *colour attributes* of the affected widget to the current "transparent"  color (i.e. the background color of the *parent* frame), e.g.

```py
Ghost_FRAME  = LabelFrame( ParentFrame, background =  'gold' )
TransparentColour =  Ghost_FRAME[  'background'  ] 
GhostWidget = Label( Ghost_FRAME, text = 'Dead parrot', background =  TransparentColour )   
GhostWidget [ 'foreground'  ] = TransparentColour
```

Which creates gold  (foreground) text on a gold widget on a gold background, making the widget effectively invisible.  (This is intentional & desired behaviour, depending upon startup mode.)  However when a different option (language) got changed some color attributes of the problem widgets also got changed irrespective of startup mode,  thus making the widget suddenly visible - and giving me the mistaken impression that grid_remove was not acting properly.

Replacing those "invisibilty" lines with grid_remove() fixed my problem.